# Send JSON data through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to send data from option selector

```
<select id="city">
    <option value="{'city':'melbourne','lat':'-37.8602828','long':'144.9631'}">Melbourne</option>
```

Through an AJAX POST

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        city: $('#city option:selected').val()
    },
})
```

However I got an empty `$_POST` in `action.php`. What is the correct way to send the value of the selected option through an AJAX request?

Comment: is value{'city':'melbourne','lat':'-37.8602828','long':'144.9631'}" is valid for value tag?

Comment: First of all you are missing equals and double quote on options value.
Second: can your print the `$('#city option:selected').val()` and let to know whats the console print for this?

Comment: i read in another stackoverflow page that its a valid value tag. (page missing)

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing `="` at the option value attribute

```
<select id="city">
    <option value="{'city':'melbourne','lat':'-37.8602828','long':'144.9631'}">Melbourne</option>
```

Plus, you can directly access the select value:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        city: $('#city').val()
    },
})
```

At the level of PHP, you have to decode the value of `$_POST['city']` to get a mapped PHP array:

```
$city = json_decode($_POST['city']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try modifying your HTML a bit as:

```
<option value='{"city":"melbourne","lat":"-37.8602828","long":"144.9631"}'>Melbourne</option>
```

`value` attributes value is within single quote and JSON data's key-value pair is in double quotes.

Also once you grab the selected value by `.val()` we are actually getting data of type `string` so before sending it; you need to parse it via `$.parseJSON(str_value)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str_value = $('#city option:selected').val();
  alert(str_value);
  alert("typeof str_value: " + typeof str_value);
  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(str_value);
  console.log(jsonData);
  alert("city " + jsonData["city"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city">
  <option value='{"city":"melbourne","lat":"-37.8602828","long":"144.9631"}'>Melbourne</option>
  <option value='{"city":"melbourne1","lat":"-37.8602828","long":"144.9631"}'>Melbourne1</option>
</select>
```